# Why does SharedPreferences need two keys?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to build a single object that handles all my `SharedPreferences`, since they are mostly used in the whole app, and I don't quite Understand why it takes two keys to get a value.

The call looks like this:

```
context.getSharedPreferences(FirstKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(SecondKey, default)
```

I get that its basically built up as a two dimensional array.
The `FirstKey` gives me a collection of key-value pairs I can use my `SecondKey` on to get my value. And I get that If I have dozens of `SharedPreferences` this might come in handy to manage them and prevent mixups/unwanted overwriting.

But is this necessary If I only have like 10 preferences I save anyway or is it reasonable to just use one `FirstKey` for all of my preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is this necessary If I only have like 10 preferences I save anyway
>   or is it reasonable to just use one FirstKey for all of my
>   preferences?

So for this case you can avoid the use of that `FirstKey` by using `getDefaultSharedPreferences()` like this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
editor.putString("myKey", "myValue");
editor.apply();
```

or read already set preferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String myPref = prefs.getString("myKey", "myDefaultValue");
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is to ***encapsulate, organize and manage*** better groups (first key values) of data you want to store (second keys values). So in case you want for example to retrieve all settings preferences you can group them by a Settings file (first key). Or in case you would like to delete all stored values regarding a user preferences (preferred language, preferred currency.. ) then you can organize those data within a "UserPref" file (first key) and then you can iterate within it to either delete all of them when you logout or whatever pogic you see useful for your user experience.

Answer (score 0):

**First key**
Retrieve and hold the contents of the preferences file

**Second key**
Retrieve and hold value in this file

Comment: I get that. My questions is more about how to use it properly. Is it reasonable to make an object that handles all Preferences and writes them all in the same file?

Comment: public static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use only your "FirstKey" for all your preferences and normally dev us it like this only. You can create multiple instances of shared preference by changing the "First key" at the time of getSharedPreference(). Suppose you want two different shared preference for two different modules in your project then change the "FirstKey" parameter, in this case, you have two be careful while storing and fetching data from preference as you have two different shared preference.

Answer (score 0):

As you rightfully stated, the first key represents a group of key-value pairs (which is actually very similar to a single file) and the second key helps you fetch the values in that file/group.

I personally believe this design is great especially in cases where you may want to separate all your values into different categories. If your app is "small", you can save all your values in one single file/group. Otherwise, you can split all your values into separate files/groups.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!